# Error 3125 when I run SQL SELECT query to fetch a row with a "."

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here is my datasheet, tblTable, in comma-delimited format:

```
Customer ID, Customer Name
1, Company Inc.
```

My VB code:

```
Public Sub ViewCustomerByJob(varCustomerName As Variant)
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblCustomer " & _
             "WHERE CustomerName = '" & varCustomerName & "'"

    Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef

    Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(strSQL)
    With qd
        .ReturnsRecords = True
        .SQL = strSQL
    End With

    DoCmd.OpenQuery (strSQL)
End Sub
```

Whenever `varCustomerName` equals "Company Inc.", MS Access throws a 3125 error:

> SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE CustomerName = 'Company Inc." is not a valid name.

That is the first sentence verbatim.

If I go to `tblCustomer` and delete the "." from "Inc.", then re-run the code, it shows the row:

```
Customer ID, Customer Name
1, Company Inc
```

Without the ".", the SQL query works, but with the ".", it breaks. Why?

Comment: I notice you have a space in the 'Customer Name' column name in your table layout, but not in your SQL...  Try adding square brackets around that field name in your SQL, and add the space if there really is one.

Comment: Screenshot of the error?

Comment: @TimWilliams Just tried that, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @Yawar here's a screenshot with TImWilliams' suggestion: http://i.imgur.com/oSEVlHD.png

Comment: @Generic_User_ID - the screenshot showed me the problem, thanks--see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is as Tim Williams has said. Suggestion: give the `QueryDef` object you're creating a name and pass that name to the `DoCmd.OpenQuery` method:

```
Public Sub ViewCustomerByJob(varCustomerName As Variant)
    dim qryName as string
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef

    qryName = "qryCustomersByJob"
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblCustomer " & _
             "WHERE CustomerName = '" & varCustomerName & "'"

    on error resume next
    currentdb.querydefs.delete qryName
    Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(qryName, strSQL)

    DoCmd.OpenQuery qryName
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that personally, I prefer to use pure SQL statements instead of using the Access object model. So instead of `QueryDefs.Delete qryName`, I would use `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "drop procedure " & qryName`, and instead of `CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(...)`, I'd use `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "create procedure ..."`.

Comment: Yep, @TimWilliams was right. I checked off this answer since it has the code, too. Thanks to the both of you.

Answer (score 3):

CreateQueryDef expects two parameters: a Name and the SQL for the query.

You are passing the SQL to the Name parameter, hence the error "...is not a valid name"

Answer (score 0):

Note that I haven't tried this out. I am sure, this will work.

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblCustomer " & _
         "WHERE [Customer Name] = cName"

Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rstTemp As Recordset 

Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(strSQL)
With qd
    .ReturnsRecords = True
    .SQL = strSQL
    .Parameters("cName") = varCustomerName 

    Set rstTemp = .OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot) 
End With

With rstTemp 
     ' Populate Recordset and print number of records. 
     .MoveLast 
     Debug.Print "  Number of records = " & _ 
        .RecordCount 
     Debug.Print 
     .Close 
End With
```

reference: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=236021
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845129%28v=office.15%29.aspx